# Decimal number-field is not working in AEM touch UI dialog

Tags: dialog, aem, aem-touch-ui, aem-core-wcm-components

I've created a number-field in AEM(6.4) touch UI dialog.
I've added step property `0.1`. I've tried using `0.01 & 0.001` as well. 
But for certain numbers, without any pattern, it doesn't allows to select them.
Dialog/Number fields gives validation error AND DOESN'T ALLOWS TO CLOSE THE DIALOG.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the issue, 
Using `step-String-0.0002` allows me to enter a decimal value up to 3 places and shows validation error beyond that.
[image]
[image]

Now, using `step-String-any`. Although, it's step value is 1, but allows me to enter any decimal value. 
[image]
[image]

Reference - 
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/numberfield/index.html

**Updated:** In the above scenarios, a step used as String or double yields the same result

Answer (score 0):

`step` should be a `double`, not a `String`.

Comment: Using step as String and not Double does not makes much of a difference.
Please refer this https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/numberfield/index.html

Comment: Interesting, for 6.5 is listed as double: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield/index.html

Comment: Well then, my issue will be resolved when we'll migrate to 6.5. Until then i can go with the solution available for for **6.4(as specified in the question)**. Thanks for digging out solution