# AEM Number Field Using Decimal value

Tags: aem

If we try using the below way it's worked using coral UI-3(granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/number field)
[linkref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Nia.png)

But not working with AEM 6.4 and if we use Coral UI-2 (granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield)

Is there a way in Coral UI-2?

Comment: “not working” is a tad unprecise. Could you elaborate? What exactly isn’t working? What are you trying to achieve, what happens instead?

Comment: Is this maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928092/decimal-number-field-is-not-working-in-aem-touch-ui-dialog?

Comment: Please add more details to what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Steps property of numberfield is used for incrementing, for "granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield" resourceType, provide the steps in string like steps="0.01" or whatever precision you want.